# How do I restore the original finish of a reglazed plastic tub?

Tags: bathtub

I bought a house a few years back. The previous owner had reglazed the plastic tub and wall unit and the glazed paint is starting to peel and looks pretty bad.

How do I remove the glazed paint to restore the original plastic?

Answer (score 2):

I seriously doubt you will be able to return the original finish. The glaze you refer to was probably not applied properly or was cheap plastic paint.  In order to refinish a fiberglass tub unit, it will have to be stripped, sanded and properly sprayed out with a multi-stage epoxy refinishing product. this is a very difficult job and not one that comes out well when done by an inexperienced installer. The average cost in this area to do what you want is around $500 for a good refinish job. A half decent new tub and surround is about the same price without install costs. I have used a lot of Kohler 4 piece units, and been very satisfied.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The fiberglass tub spray paint is peeling off, I was quoted 800.00 to remove the old paint and 800.00 to re-spray. Why re-spray if the first time was not working?  Try to find a way not to put a new unit in..

Comment: You can buy do it yourself tub spray kits for around $100. The trick is preping the surfaces properly and appling the sprays evenly. This may get you by a few years, but will never look or perform like a new unit. A new unit can be installed and plumbed in less than a day. If you are willing to cut up and remove the old unit, get the new tub in place, a skilled person can secure it and plumb it in a few hours. that might be your most cost effective move.

Comment: The old spray likely failed because of insufficient prep or poor application. So a respray may work better--if you put in the elbow grease to prep the surface.